# How do I bring 1 of 3 movie clips to the front and make it stay there? (Flash CS5, AS 3.0)

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs5, movieclip

I have three movie clips that I want to bring to front when I click on the associated tag. Flash cs5 and actionscript 3.0. The coding for each looks like this:

status_mc.status_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, callFunction_stat);

function callFunction_stat(e:MouseEvent): void {

if (getChildIndex(status_mc) == 0) {setChildIndex(status_mc, 1) } else {setChildIndex(status_mc, 0)} ;
}

This sends the movie clip /back/ instead of forwards though it does allow me to view each clip on top. My question is, how do I bring each of the 3 movie clips to the front when I click on it, and if it /is/ in the front, make it remain so/no change when clicked?

Answer (score 0):

To bring a display object to the front (IE:on top of all other display objects) you simply need to `addChild(status_mc)`